# If a composition of linear transformation is invertible, then are each linear transformations invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If $S$ and $T$ are linear transformations from set $V$ to $V$, which is a finite-dimensional vector space, and if the composition $ST$ is invertible, how can we show that $T$ is one-to-one, therefore, invertible, and also that $S$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $ST$ is invertible if and only if $\det(ST)=\det(S)\det(T)\ne0$ so $\det(S)\ne0$ and $\det(T)\ne0$ and then $S$ and $T$ are both invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Take $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ such that $T{\bf x} = T{\bf y}$. Apply $S$. Then $ST{\bf x} = ST{\bf y}$, and we get ${\bf x} = {\bf y}$. In general, $\ker T \subset \ker ST $. So $T$ is injective, hence bijective (using finite dimension).

Now, let ${\bf z} \in \mathcal{V}$. Exists ${\bf x}$ such that $ST{\bf x} = {\bf z}$. Then, ${\bf y} = T{\bf x} \in \mathcal{V}$ satisfies $S{\bf y} = {\bf z}$, and $S$ is onto. So $S$ is bijective (using finite dimension).